# Debugging QuickExport Parameters in Data Interoperability Extension for Exporting to PostgreSQL?

Tags: arcpy, postgis, postgresql, export, parameters

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.

I tried to configure the QuickExport parameters by examining the log file after I used the QuickExport tool itself. The only things I changed from the log file are the parameters as I want the user to be able to input the parameters to connect to a postgres database after they create it and pass in a layer. Any suggestions on debugging this? I didn't get any syntax errors, but if the tool didn't work I made it throw an exception.

```
arcpy.QuickExport_interop(layer, POSTGIS, dbname,"RUNTIME_MACROS,""HOST,%s,PORT,%d,USER_NAME,%s,PASSWORD,%s,GENERIC_GEOMETRY,no,\
LOWERCASE_ATTRIBUTE_NAMES,Yes"",META_MACROS,""DestHOST,%s,DestPORT,%d,DestUSER_NAME,%s,DestPASSWORD,%s,DestGENERIC_GEOMETRY,no, \
DestLOWERCASE_ATTRIBUTE_NAMES,Yes"",METAFILE,POSTGIS,COORDSYS,,__FME_DATASET_IS_SOURCE_,false" %((server),(portnum),(usrName),(passWord),(server),(portnum),(usrName),(passWord)))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can export your data to a shp file, you can use the [shp2pgsql](http://www.bostongis.com/pgsql2shp_shp2pgsql_quickguide.bqg) tool that comes with postgis.